# Cannot access dashboard after upgrading to 3.5

Tags: dashboard, upgrade, fatal-error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_taxonomies_for_attachments() in D:\hosting\10111755\html\wp-admin\menu.php on line 67

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like the WordPress update failed. The good news is that it's an easy fix. Simply download the files and re-upload them.

You can follow the instructions here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update